# Golden Angle Golden Spiral

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, curves, golden-ratio

**Note.** The answer must produce something self-similar that progresses in such a manner regardless of whether positive or negative values are graphed.

**Note.** The "distance between 'arcs'" I'm talking about is defined in my image (the red dotted line represents such a distance between 'arcs').

The parametric equations, $x,\ y=\sin(t)·φ^{t/π},\ \cos(t)·φ^{t/π}$, yield a spiral where the distance between the 'arcs' grows (/shrinks) gradually reaching powers of $φ$ at every multiple of $π$ (every $180$ degrees). ([See My Graph.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rjygz9cxzr))

I want to find parametric equations for a spiral where this distance grows (/shrinks) **by powers of φ** in exactly the same way relative to multiples of the golden angle, that is, $\frac{2π}{φ}$ (**Instead of doing so relative to π**). ($φ$ is defined as $φ=\left(\frac{1+5^{1/2}}{2}\right)$ herein!)

Such a thing seems totally possible; however I have had little luck thus far. So, I'd be thankful for some help! Thanks.

[image]

**Graph:**

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0iotz6gmdu

Comment: **If you don't understand something about my post, please feel free to ask!**

Comment: In polar coordinates, $(r,\theta)=(f(t),t)$, it appears that you want $$f(k\omega)-f(k\omega-2\pi) = \phi^{k+c}$$ for integer $k$, where $\omega:=2\pi/\phi$ (or whatever angular step you'd care to take) and $c$ is there just to match the desired multiple of $\omega$ with the desired power of $\phi$. The continuous, $k$-less version of the target relation would be $$f(t)-f(t-2\pi)=\phi^{(t/\omega)+c}$$ Does this seem correct to you?

Comment: @Blue Yes. That perfectly formalizes what I want!

Comment: You, @Blue are awesome, it must be said! Also, an interesting thing I noted is that when I tried to derive the function myself, whenever I modified it to yield a good approximation on one part of the spiral, the other parts were way off (this happened for multiple strategies): I wonder what this will turn out to mean in the context of the correct function!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding-upon comment, if we consider polar coordinates $(r,\theta)=(f(t),t)$, with initial condition that the curve passes through $(x,y)=(b,0)$, then the curve's defining relation is
$$f(k\omega) - f(k\omega-2\pi) = \phi^{k+c} = \exp_\phi(k+c) \qquad\qquad f(0) = b\tag{1}$$
where $\omega := 2\pi/\phi$, $k$ is an integer, and $c$ is there just to make sure the multiples of $\omega$ match with the appropriate powers of $\phi$. The continuous, $k$-free version of $(1)$ is

> $$f(t)-f(t-2\pi) = \exp_\phi\left(\frac{t}{\omega}+c\right) \qquad\qquad f(0)=b \tag{2}$$

Suppose the solution has the form
$$f(t) = a\left(\phi^{t/\omega}-1\right) + b \tag{3}$$
Then $(2)$ requires
$$\exp_\phi\left(\frac{t}{\omega}+c\right) = a\exp_\phi\left(\frac{t}{\omega}\right) - a\exp_\phi\left(\frac{t}{\omega}-\frac{2\pi}{\omega}\right)
= a\exp_\phi\left(\frac{t}{\omega}\right) - a\exp_\phi\left(\frac{t}{\omega}-\phi\right) \tag{4}$$
Dividing the left-most and right-most expressions by $\phi^{t/\omega}$,
$$\phi^c = a - a\phi^{-\phi} \qquad\to\qquad a = \frac{\phi^{\phi+c}}{\phi^\phi-1}
\tag{5}$$
so that $(3)$ becomes

> $$f(t) = \frac{\phi^{\phi+c}}{\phi^\phi-1}\left(\phi^{t/\omega}-1\right) + b \tag{$\star$}$$

Comment: @JinnyEcckle: I don't understand what you mean. Be that as it may ... Since you emphatically agreed with my comment's formalization of your question, changing the conditions after the fact is bad form. You should post (yet another :) new question.

Answer (score 3):

You may parametrize the proposed spiral as

$$x=\sin(t)·\phi^{\frac{t\phi}{2\pi}},\>\>\>\>\>y =\cos(t)·\phi^{\frac{t\phi}{2\pi}}$$

which yields the distance between the arcs grows/shrinks gradually reaching powers of $\phi$ at every multiple of $\frac{2\pi}\phi$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Quanto, but you seem to have inverted what I asked about: I want a spiral that grows / shrinks by powers of $ϕ$ at multiples of the golden angle, not one that grows by powers of the golden angle at multiples of $π$.

Comment: Anyhow, thank you.

Comment: see my *updated* question.

Comment: @JinnyEcckle - Thanks for clarification. I modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, When you say, "which yields the distance between the arcs grows/shrinks gradually reaching powers of ϕ at every multiple of ϕ." Do you mean every multiple of $\frac{2π}{φ}$?

Comment: @JinnyEcckle - I assume multiple of $\phi$. I guess you need multiples of $2\pi/\phi$. I modified.

Comment: unfortunately, this spiral does not have the property described.

Comment: See link, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5zohp8vdon @Quanto .

Comment: this is a tricky one, isn't it?! Also, note, if you try to work on it more, I'd rather parameterize it outside of the the sine / cosine functions, that is, I'd like: $x, \ y = f(t)⋅\sin(t), \ f(t)⋅\sin(t)$.

Comment: The issue you ran into here, it seems to me, is that when you use $ϕ$ as you do, the instances cancel out, thus making the whole the the same as $x,\ y=\sin(t)·φ^{t/π},\ \cos(t)·φ^{t/π}$.

Comment: @JinnyEcckle - Yeah, it's tricky. Let me take another look.

Comment: Thank You! :) I appreciate the work!

Comment: @JinnyEcckle - I removed the cancelling factor in the two trig functions. I think it should work now. Give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, this function (which I've measured in the past), appears to give powers of phi from 'arcs' to the origin, but **not** in the distances between 'arcs.'

Comment: Nevertheless thank you for all the effort, it is an extremely tricky function to formulate!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are seeking a spiral that increases by a factor of $\varphi$ for every angular change of $2\pi/\varphi$. This is the very definition of the logarithmic spiral, which is given in complex and Cartesian coordinates as follows

$$
z=e^{(b+i)\theta}\\
x=e^{b\theta}\cos\theta\\
y=e^{b\theta}\sin\theta
$$

where $b$ is the flair coefficient, which is defined as the logarithm of the growth rate, say $p$, divided by the angular change, say $\Delta\theta$, thus

$$b=\ln(p)/\Delta\theta$$

For example, for the golden spiral we have $b=2\ln\varphi/\pi$, or a growth of $\varphi$ per $90^{\circ}$. In your case, the solution is

$$b=\frac{\varphi\ln\varphi}{2\pi}$$

The figure below shows a comparison of these two spirals. Clearly, the golden spiral grows at a much faster rate, namely, $4/\varphi$[image: golden ratio spiral comparison].